# Using slice or splice to remove array from a "multidimentional" array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, slice, splice

I am having trouble removing an object from a 2D array. The object I am trying to remove is also an array.

```
var symbolsArray=[
   ["a","b","c","d"],
   [1,2,3,4,5],
   ["č","ž","š"],       // remove this whole array only
   ["1","2","3","4"]
]
```

I have been trying to remove it using slice, when it did not work also with splice. What is happening is that the first level array becomes empty after the operation or it has only one object inside it left.

I looked up [SLICE](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) and [SPLICE](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) methods and thought that slice is the way to go in my case. When it didnt work, I also tryes splice.

Is it maybe a problem beacuse I am trying to use it on a "multidimensional" array?

Comment: `symbolsArray.splice(2,1);`.

Comment: _"When it didnt work"_ -- how did it not work? Please add the code you tried to the question.

Comment: @Kind user: When I do this, I end up with var symbolsArray=[["č","ž","š"]]. So only one array inside the primary one.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: usualy I would get either an empty primary array or an array with only one element

Comment: @user2375263: `splice` returns the removed item, and changes the array. Don't assing the return value of `splice` to `symbolsArray`

Comment: @Cerbrus: that was the issue! Thank you everybody!